# How to list only the last line of each directory?

Tags: command-line, sed, find, ls

I learned thanks to you, how to display only the last line of a listing,e.g.

```
ls -ltr | sed '$!d'
```

Now I thought, how to combine it with the find command, in order to repeat this onto each directory exitent, but I got only to a false solution:

```
find / -type d | xargs ls -ltr | sed '$!d'
```

If i read it right, this would not display the last line of each directory, but only the last line of all listings of all directories.

How to do it right ?

Comment: I think report of your listing via -l make problem for you , you can eliminate -l and use `|wc -l` for test

Answer (score 2):

Probably this would be better: combination of find and shell

```
find / -type d -print0 | while read -r -d '' dir; do 
    ls -ltr "$dir" | sed '$!d'
done
```

`find` will output each directory found, using the null byte instead of a newline to separate them. This stream is fed into a `while` loop, using `read -d ''` to extract each null-delimited directory name. Then, for each directory, all but the last line of `ls` output is deleted by `sed`.

The key is that the `while` loop iterates over each directory name, so the most recent file is found for every directory.

One big problem with this is that `ls -l` output does not show you the directory name, so the output probably won't make much sense -- you see files but without knowing which directory they appear in.

To find the newest file in each directory, I would do this:

```
find . -type f -printf "%h:%T@:%p\n" |
sort -t: -k1,1r -k2,2nr |
awk -F: '!seen[$1]++ {print $3}'
```

- `find` to get the directory, mod time, and path name
- `sort` to group by directory and sort by time
- `awk` to print the pathname that is the first for each directory

Comment: thank you for the code, though I do not understand it in detail

Comment: Any part in particular?

Comment: I do not understand how the while loop works with sed '$!d',  so that sed is applied to each listing of each folder every time though it looks like it would be applied only once because it is the last in the pipe-chain.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use this kind of construct as a starting point

```
find / -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -I'{}' sh -c 'ls -ltr {} | tail -1'
```

Caveat: it doesn't like empty directories (`total 0` is output).