# What is the meaning of read -r?

Tags: shell, read

In order to understand [another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/192766/80216#192769) (by glenn jackman):

```
find / -type d -print0 | while read -r -d '' dir; do ls -ltr "$dir" | sed '$!d'; done
```

the first step is to understand the usage of the option `-r` of the `read` command.

First, I thought, it would be sufficient to simply execute

```
man read
```

to look up the meaning of the `-r` option, but I realized the man page does not contain any explanation for options at all, so I Googled for it. 
I got some `read -t`, `read -p` examples, but no `read -r`.

Comment: It's a shell built in (at least in bash) - try `help read` or `man bash`

Comment: Regarding your title question, read http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18886/why-is-while-ifs-read-used-so-often-instead-of-ifs-while-read/18936#18936

Comment: `READ(1P)` exists for me...

Comment: This is highly confusing for beginners, since there is also a command line tool `read` as well and `man read` will show the info for that.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

There is no stand-alone `read` command: instead, it is a shell built-in, and as such is documented in the man page for `bash`:

> `read [-ers] [-a aname] [-d delim] [-i text] [-n nchars] [-N nchars] [-p prompt] [-t timeout] [-u fd] [name ...]`
>
>   ︙
>   **`-r`**
>     Backslash does not act as an escape character. 
>     The backslash is considered to be part of the line. 
>     In  particular,  a  backslash-newline pair may not be used as a line
>     continuation.

So, to summarize, `read` normally allows long lines to be broken using a trailing backslash character, and normally reconstructs such lines. This slightly surprising behavior can be deactivated using `-r`.

Comment: A demo: `str="a\bc"; read x <<< "$str"; read -r y <<< "$str"; echo "$x"; echo "$y"`

Comment: @glennjackman That's great, it's even more striking if you type `str="a\` and then hit Enter before pasting in the rest of the command starting with `b`.

Comment: Why do you consider line continuation by backslash+newline to be the least bit surprising? It’s standard shell behavior, and is documented in the “[QUOTING](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#QUOTING)” section of the man page: “ **``\``** <newline> is treated as a line continuation”. Try typing ``da\`` (Enter) ```te``` (Enter).

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica': That's an excellent question, and, thinking about it, while it is true that `read` is consistent with Bash's input-parsing behavior for its own commands, I would say it is rather unusual for a programming language's equivalent read function to do line splicing; for example, C source code also supports backslash line continuations, but `fread` and friends do not do any such magic. I also can't immediately think of another language with a standard input-reading function that does this.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' I think the the surprise of backslash+newline is more about how source code editors/viewers may not always be configured with enough visual cues to help readers check if a line ends in whitespace.

Comment: Demo: `demo() { backslash='\' newline=$'\n'; bash -c "echo wrapped line with $backslash$1$newline date"; }; demo ''; demo ' '`

Comment: From a reader's perspective, it can be hard to differentiate between `echo wrapped line with \ ` followed by a new line, compared to ``echo wrapped line with \`` followed by a new line!

Comment: @Moh: While continuing a line with a backslash is treacherous because whitespace after the backslash breaks it, I don’t see how this conversation is about that.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica': Apologies if I went off-topic. I guess the surprise factor really depends on the context that backslash+newline occurs in. I think that I accidentally conflated several different contexts together: viewing script code vs. a script usage of `read` from interactive user input vs. a script usage of `read` for parsing command output

Comment: IIUC, neither `read` nor `read -r` can accept multiple lines due to the default newline delimiter, and `read -rd ''` seems to work well to accept multiple lines from interactive user input as long as the user knows how to send a null character (e.g. C-v C-@). So I guess the most unintuitive/surprising usage is `read -d ''` which is probably something to avoid 99% of the time and can lead to surprising results if a user copy-pastes multi-line input from an editor with unintentional invisible whitespace between the backslash+newline combo

Comment: @Moh: It may be true that ```read -d ''``` should probably be avoided *for interactive user input.*  Did you notice that, in the question, it is used to read from a pipe?  Specifically, a pipe from ```find … -print0```, which uses null characters as record separators.

Answer (score 20):

The `-r` option **prevents backslash escapes from being interpreted**. Here's an example:

Assume there's a file with this content:

```
ngRTM6hNqgziZcqCcEJN7bHAP9a1GeMs\
Ni3EAX1qvogWpRIPE3oagJL6nwl\QQW9y
bjJHyaVBrUcyZOY5U4h9QHnpEPqg\\\\\\\\\Q9Fk
iNOvAyBTAcN5n1uwR4GvRfAGUbPWiXax\n
cqGPPStH3gaWolrfVAlMtoWiSuLa7GzQ\n\n\n
EnO04N1nEkpWbfXRxrtYNqCZDpF\trQIXS
```

```
$ while read line; do echo $line; done < tempfile
ngRTM6hNqgziZcqCcEJN7bHAP9a1GeMsNi3EAX1qvogWpRIPE3oagJL6nwlQQW9y
bjJHyaVBrUcyZOY5U4h9QHnpEPqg\\\\Q9Fk
iNOvAyBTAcN5n1uwR4GvRfAGUbPWiXaxn
cqGPPStH3gaWolrfVAlMtoWiSuLa7GzQnnn
EnO04N1nEkpWbfXRxrtYNqCZDpFtrQIXS
```

```
$ while read -r line; do echo $line; done < tempfile
ngRTM6hNqgziZcqCcEJN7bHAP9a1GeMs\
Ni3EAX1qvogWpRIPE3oagJL6nwl\QQW9y
bjJHyaVBrUcyZOY5U4h9QHnpEPqg\\\\\\\\\Q9Fk
iNOvAyBTAcN5n1uwR4GvRfAGUbPWiXax\n
cqGPPStH3gaWolrfVAlMtoWiSuLa7GzQ\n\n\n
EnO04N1nEkpWbfXRxrtYNqCZDpF\trQIXS
```

Answer (score 5):

The Bash man page's [section](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#SHELL_BUILTIN_COMMANDS) about `read` states that, by default...

> The backslash character
> (**`\`**) may be used to remove any special meaning for the next character  read  and for  line continuation.

but, if you pass `-r`, then

> Backslash does not act as an escape character. 
> The backslash  is considered to be part of the line. 
> In particular, a backslash-newline pair may not then be used as a line continuation.

A little thought suggests that the only possible "special meaning" they could be talking about is the character serving as a delimiter. And sure enough, *without* `-r`, you can backslash-escape a delimiter or a newline, but *with* `-r`, you can't, and backslashes just get interpreted as literal backslashes:

```
$ read -d 'x'    var1 <<< 'There was once \
a curious Uni\x user.xHe did a little test.'
$ echo "$var1"
There was once a curious Unix user.
$ read -d 'x' -r var2 <<< 'There was once \
a curious Uni\x user.xHe did a little test.'
$ echo "$var2"
There was once \
a curious Uni\
```