# GNU parallel bash

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel

I am learning GNU parallel and I wonder it this makes sense:

bash:

```
    IFS=" "
while read field || [ -n "$field" ]; do
    targets_array+=("$field")
    
done </location/targets
 
parallel  -Dall bash myScript.sh ::: $targets_array
```

**I wonder if it makes sense because my output seem to stop at some point...**
I have 30.000 targets that I scan with myScript.sh
then I update info about them in DB also using myScript.sh

I tried to use some options but I could not make it work: like writing to a logfile
from the performance point of view, does it make sense to run one target at the time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$targets_array` is equivalent to `${targets_array[0]}`. To get all elements you need `${targets_array[@]}`. And you should [quote right](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618).

So it could be:

```
parallel … ::: "${targets_array[@]}"               # but don't
```

`parallel` is an external command. If the array is large enough then you will hit `argument list too long`. Use this instead:

```
printf '%s\n' "${targets_array[@]}" | parallel …   # still not the best
```

It will work better because in Bash `printf` is a builtin and therefore everything before `|` is handled internally by Bash.

I notice you didn't use [`read -r`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/192790/108618) (I assume it was an educated decision), so a backslash-newline pair (if any) in `/location/targets` can result in a newline character actually in some array element. Therefore separating with newlines while passing data to `parallel` may be a bug. Separate with null bytes:

```
printf '%s\0' "${targets_array[@]}" | parallel -0 …
```

Hopefully `/location/targets` does not contain null bytes. If it does then [they won't get to the array](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/174017/108618) in the first place.

Comment: I don't really see the point of the array at all actually. Why not just read `targets` directly with `parallel`?

Comment: @Kusalananda Because I assume `read` without `-r` was an educated decision. I'm not aware of GNU `parallel`'s ability to handle backslash equivalently. Can it do this?

Comment: I assumed that this was an omission in the question. Setting `IFS` to a space character  indicates that they either don't know what this does (and that omitting `-r` was a mistake), or that they explicitly want to trim flanking spaces from the input data (in which case omitting `-r` may have been on purpose also). Unfortunately, the question does not tell.

Comment: @Kusalananda The answer is now community wiki. If you think it should elaborate on the lack of `-r` or provide a command to read `targets` directly with `parallel` then please improve it. Unfortunately I have no time for this now.

Comment: @Kusalananda  It looks like the omission of -r was a mistake, I tried to set the field separator as a space and read target after target separated by space from the file.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I tried to cat the file and It would not work, it treated my targets as a command, I will come up with some good example if I have some more time. Thank you for your contribution, It was very helpful.